# Applocker - Publisher rule not working

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-registry, applocker

In a bit to reduce the number of Applocker Packaged apps rules now that we are using the private store. We're looking into publisher only rules (right now, we have 1 rule per microsoft store application).

We would like to put one rule for all Microsoft application. (helping us reduce 90% of the rules).

Trying to figure out why my Publisher only rule isn't working.

For simplicity, I've trimmed down the rule to only the windows store. It runs and opens fine.

```
    <AppLockerPolicy Version="1">
  <RuleCollection Type="Appx" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured">
    <FilePublisherRule Id="963d36c4-c0dd-4831-b4f4-240bd4b75813" Name="Packaged app: Microsoft.WindowsStore, version 12001.1001.1.0, from Microsoft Corporation" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" ProductName="Microsoft.WindowsStore" BinaryName="*">
          <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="0.0.0.0" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
      </Conditions>
    </FilePublisherRule>
  </RuleCollection>
  <RuleCollection Type="Dll" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured" />
  <RuleCollection Type="Exe" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured" />
  <RuleCollection Type="Msi" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured" />
  <RuleCollection Type="Script" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured" />
</AppLockerPolicy>
```

if i put this policy rule (Allow all Microsoft signed apps), the store is blocked

```
<AppLockerPolicy Version="1">
  <RuleCollection Type="Appx" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured">
    <FilePublisherRule Id="939fb295-f744-4298-bc31-be2e6178c15e" Name="Signed by Microsoft Corporation" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" ProductName="*" BinaryName="*">
          <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
      </Conditions>
    </FilePublisherRule>
  </RuleCollection>
  <RuleCollection Type="Dll" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured" />
  <RuleCollection Type="Exe" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured" />
  <RuleCollection Type="Msi" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured" />
  <RuleCollection Type="Script" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured" />
</AppLockerPolicy>
```

[image: Store is blocked]

If i then enable the store and the all Microsoft publish apps, then store comes up but then none of the curated apps from Microsoft are allowed.

```
<AppLockerPolicy Version="1">
  <RuleCollection Type="Appx" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured">
    <FilePublisherRule Id="963d36c4-c0dd-4831-b4f4-240bd4b75813" Name="Packaged app: Microsoft.WindowsStore, version 12001.1001.1.0, from Microsoft Corporation" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" ProductName="Microsoft.WindowsStore" BinaryName="*">
          <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="0.0.0.0" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
      </Conditions>
    </FilePublisherRule>
    <FilePublisherRule Id="939fb295-f744-4298-bc31-be2e6178c15e" Name="Signed by Microsoft Corporation" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
      <Conditions>
        <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" ProductName="*" BinaryName="*">
          <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*" />
        </FilePublisherCondition>
      </Conditions>
    </FilePublisherRule>
  </RuleCollection>
  <RuleCollection Type="Dll" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured" />
  <RuleCollection Type="Exe" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured" />
  <RuleCollection Type="Msi" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured" />
  <RuleCollection Type="Script" EnforcementMode="NotConfigured" />
</AppLockerPolicy>
```

[image: Blocked Microsoft app]

Here's what my registry looks like under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\SrpV2\Appx
2 rules - Store and all Microsoft

[image: Applocker Registry with 2 rules]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went looking in the event log (Microsoft -> Windows -> Applocker -> Package app-Deployment) for blocked entries.

The general tab wasn't very helpful but then I went in the xml details and found the correct publisher value

```
<FilePublisherRule Id="939fb295-f744-4298-bc31-be2e6178c15f" Name="Signed by Microsoft Corporation (Different CN)" Description="" UserOrGroupSid="S-1-1-0" Action="Allow">
  <Conditions>
    <FilePublisherCondition PublisherName="CN=MICROSOFT CORPORATION, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" ProductName="*" BinaryName="*">
      <BinaryVersionRange LowSection="*" HighSection="*" />
    </FilePublisherCondition>
  </Conditions>
</FilePublisherRule>
```